# What is the origin of all the tenses in Spanish? -- e.g yo escribí

Tags: etimología, pretérito

When conjugating preterite, it seems odd that the  -é/í  ending is used for the yo form while the -ó/ió is used for the él form.

In the present tense, -o is used for the yo form while -e is (for er/ir verbs) used in the él form.

It seems as though these endings are switched in the preterite tense. Is there any good reason why this is (historically, or something else) or a deeper explanation, or is this just a quirk of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Because Latin.

Spanish endings are derived from Latin endings.  In Latin, in most all tenses, the endings were the following:

```
-o/m  -mus
-s    -tis
-t    -nt
```

These would have preserved the vowel that came first with an infix for tense.  Hence for *amare* you got:

```
    pres.                          imp.
    -----                         -----
          o mus   amo  amus              m mus   amabam amabamus
AMA + Ø + s tis = amas atis   AMA + BA + s tis = amabas amabatis
          t nt    amat aman              t nt    amabat amabant
```

The word-final -m and -t were lost, the -atis became -ades for a while before eventually becoming -ais.  The -u- in -amus raised to an -o-.

This worked for almost all conjugations in active voice, except for the perfect aspect.  It had its own endings that were

```
-i    -imus
-isti -istis
-it   -erunt
```

You can probably see how these relate to the simple preterite endings in Spanish (note all other perfects in Spanish are formed with *haber* leaving simple preterite as the only one retaining these endings).  They also effectively had an infix of -u/v-, such that, returning to the last verb, you get

```
          i    imus    amavi    amavimus
AMA + V + isti istis = amavisti amavistis
          it   erunt   amavit   amaverunt
```

Remember that the *v* here is vocalic so that *amavit* would have been basically *amáuit*.  Recall the *-t* got lost, and a standard transformation towards Spanish is *au*->*o* (like *aurum* -> *oro*).  This resulted in (roughly) amavit -> amavi -> amoi -> amó.  For one reason or another, the *amavi* overtime ended up as *amé* (my guess would be *amavi* -> *amai* -> *amei* -> *amé*).

Answer (score 0):

About the imperfect future tense (comeré, cantarás, viviremos):
Is formed with the infinitive and the verb "habere" ("have") in latin.

Amare habeo ----> Amar he ------> Amaré

It means "I have to love".

Currently it is again preferring another circumlocution:
"Amaré" is rarely used (formal), and instead preferred "Voy a amar", that it means "I am going to love";